# Computer Generated Vocals

Tags: generated

Is this even possible? I.e. suppose you were given:

```
1) Lyrics to a song.
2) Background music of a song.
3) Timing of what syllables should be uttered when.
4) What note what each syllable should hit.
```

Given the above, is it possible to automatically generated the vocals via a computer program?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. For example, http://www.oddcast.com/technologies/sing/  It's a combination of speech synthesis and musical synthesizers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial program out there that does this I think, though I haven't used it.

http://www.vocaloid.com/product.html

Answer (score 1):

A TTS library + http://www.surina.net/soundtouch/

Answer (score 1):

I know that this album was produced using the speech function on a mac and auto-tune: http://the-robot.bandcamp.com/